# Update multiple columns in MySql with results from a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

Background: I have an orders table that contains address columns. I would like to update these with randomly picked addresses taken from a temporary table

Both tables contain address, address1, city and postcode columns

I was thinking the query would be something like:

```
UPDATE orders (address, address1, city, postcode)
VALUE
(SELECT address, address1, city, postcode
FROM addresses
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1)
```

Edit: Note that it needs update all rows with different values.

Comment: Use multiple-table UPDATE syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE orders 
JOIN ( SELECT address, address1, city, postcode
       FROM addresses
       ORDER BY RAND()
       LIMIT 1 
       ) AS newdata
SET orders.address = newdata.address,
    orders.address1 = newdata.address1,
    orders.city = newdata.city,
    orders.postcode = newdata.postcode
WHERE orders.id = 72;
```

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly for one row, however when I remove the where clause at the end all rows are getting the same data. I need each row to be a different random selection from the addresses table.

Comment: @Barnaby I help to solve posted task only. If you have another task then create another question.